# perfmon counters can be selected but don't display data

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, perfmon

I can select perfmon counters, but not all the selected counters will display.  For example: Processor/% Idle/_TOTAL is selectable but doesn't appear in the log file.  Yet, 
Processor   /% Priviledge Time  /_TOTAL is selectalbe and does appear in the log file.  What can I look at to fix this?  Thank you.

Running Windows 2008 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the Windows 2008 perfmon issue.

Apparently, the counters were all being logged just not displaying.  Opening up properties and right clicking on the counters opened up the option to display graphically.

Comment: Mark your answer as correct.